# Confused with the second variable of task : some_random_name1, [:some_random_name2] => :environment in rake?

Tags: ruby, syntax, rake

I am new to ruby and rake, and currently confused with some ruby syntax.

```
task :some_random_name1, [:some_random_name2] => :environment do |task, args|
end
```

What does [:some_random_name2] here mean? I know some_random_name1 is a task that depends on another task :environment, and task and args in |task, args| are arguments from command line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[:some_random_name2] is referring to arguments that you can pass into your rake task. May I suggest checking out [this](http://viget.com/extend/protip-passing-parameters-to-your-rake-tasks) article which can explain in more depth passing arguments to a rake task.

When you call rake -T from the command line, you should see:

```
rake example: some_random_name1[some_random_name2]
```

(assuming your namespace is 'example')